# Valgrind throws invalid free() when I try to free an array of dynamically allocated pointers

Tags: c, arrays, unix, malloc, free

I'm allocating an array of pointers that are dynamically allocated and I try to free them at the end of my program. The problem is that I always get a "invalid free()" error on valgrind, though I really couldn't find what is wrong.
For an example: I'm allocating memory using malloc for argv[0] and argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB8Ay.png), and then try to free them in the for loop. 
I allocate the array of pointers using:

```
char ucom[10], bin[15] = "/bin/";
char* str = (char *) malloc(MAX_LINE_LENGTH*sizeof(char));
char** argv = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char*)); //ALLOCATING MEMORY FOR ARGV
int status, i = 0;
printf("Shell2$**");
strcpy(bin, "/bin/");
fgets(str, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, stdin); 
char *token;
token = strsep(&str, " ");
while(token != NULL && i < 4){
    if(token[strlen(token)-1] == '\n')
        token[strlen(token)-1] = '\0';
    argv[i] = (char *) malloc(MAX_ARGUMENT_LENGTH*sizeof(char)); //ALLOCATING MEMORY FOR POINTERS INSIDE ARGV, running two times in my example
    printf("\n\nI:%d\n\n",i);
    if(argv[i] == NULL) printf("Memory Allocation Problem");
    argv[i] = token;    
    token = strsep(&str, " ");
    i++;
    argv = (char **)realloc(argv, (i+2)*sizeof(char*));
}
```

then I try to free them up:

```
wait(&status);
for(int f = 0; f < i; f++){
    if(argv[f] != NULL)
        free(argv[f]); //Free runs two times as the number of time malloc has been called, but fails at the second free.
}
free(str);
free(argv);
```

even though the malloc ran 2 times in my example, which allocated memory for argv[0] and argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB8Ay.png), when the for loop at the end tries to free argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB8Ay.png), it fails and valgrind says it's a free invalid, but it succeeded freeing argv[0].

Thank you all in advance!

The output from valgrind:
[LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB8Ay.png)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's not productive to try and comment on incomplete code as the problem may not even be in the part you have shown. For example, is the allocation code inside a function? A common error is to allocate memory to a local scope variable and free in the caller. But we can't tell from your incomplete code if that is the case. Hence why we always ask for a minimal verifiable example.

Comment: `argv[i] = token;` -- oops, you just clobbered that memory allocation you did two lines before. Perhaps you meant to `strcpy(argv[i], token);`?

Comment: Your `argv` array starts with one element, and it's extended by one pointer each loop, so it always has one more item than there are arguments (which is reasonabl), but the final pointer is not nulled out.  Recommend `argv[i] = NULL;` after the while loop.

Comment: Can I ask you to edit and reduce unnecessary indentation? It would improve readability, especially for those reading through mobile devices (like me).

Comment: You need to include the output from Valgrind *as text* *inside the question*.

Comment: Thank you all.
@kaylum, thank you, I'll do it next time.

Comment: @FredLarson that was it ! thank you!

Comment: @AlonBarenboim: That was one, at least. I think SteveFriedl's comment likely points out another.

Comment: @FredLarson I embedded just part of my code. The next line that doesn't appear here is what Steve Fiedl talked about. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more wrong than just what @FredLarson and I have already pointed out.

The function `strsep()` actually modifies the pointer handed to it, so `char *token = strsep(&str, " ")`; **changes the pointer**. Since `str` was gotten from `malloc`, it can't be freed properly.

If you want to call `strsep()` on malloc'd memory, you have to save a copy of the original pointer and free it at the end.

Also, the not strictly portable but highly available function `strdup()` is really helpful for making a copy of a string, so rather than allocate a bunch of memory and then copy a string to it, you can just `strdup()` that string (and free it later).

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE // for strsep
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH     80
#define MAX_ARGUMENT_LENGTH 10  // made up numbers

int main()
{
    char *str = malloc(MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
    char *str_save = str;
    char **argv = malloc(sizeof(char*)); //ALLOCATING MEMORY FOR ARGV
    int i = 0;

    printf("Shell2$**"); fflush(stdout); // make sure user sees the prompt
    strcpy(bin, "/bin/");
    fgets(str, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, stdin);

    char *token;

    while ( (token = strsep(&str, " ")) != NULL  &&  i < 4 )
    {
        if(token[strlen(token)-1] == '\n')
            token[strlen(token)-1] = '\0';

        argv[i] = strdup(token);

        if(argv[i] == NULL) printf("Memory Allocation Problem");
        i++;
        argv = realloc(argv, i * sizeof(char*));
    }
    argv[i] = NULL; // GOOD IDEA TO ADD THIS

    // run the shell
    // wait(&status);

    for(int f = 0; f < i; f++){
        if(argv[f] != NULL)
            free(argv[f]);
    }
    free(str_save);
    free(argv);
}
```

This does essentially what yours does, but in practice you probably don't even need to allocate the memory for the input line. Why not just define a local buffer? Then you don't have to allocate for the line buffer *or the tokens* because they all live in `linebuffer`:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE // for strsep
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH     80

int main()
{
    char **argv = malloc(sizeof(char*)); //ALLOCATING MEMORY FOR ARGV
    int i = 0;

    printf("Shell2$**"); fflush(stdout); // make sure user sees the prompt

    char linebuf[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    fgets(linebuf, sizeof linebuf, stdin);

    char *token;
    char *str = linebuf;

    while ( (token = strsep(&str, " ")) != NULL  &&  i < 4 )
    {
        if (token[strlen(token)-1] == '\n')
            token[strlen(token)-1] = '\0';

        argv[i++] = token;

        argv = realloc(argv, i * sizeof(char*));
    }
    argv[i] = NULL; // GOOD IDEA TO ADD THIS

    // run the shell
    // wait(&status);

    free(argv);
}
```

This removes a whole lot of complications with - as far as I can tell - no less safety.